# Installation Error with Anaconda Jupyter Notebook and CLTK

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm just getting started in Python and installed Anaconda and am using that to launch Jupyter Notebooks (currently 6.5.2). I'm using Windows 11 and Chrome if that matters at all.

I want to use the Classical Language Toolkit https://docs.cltk.org/en/latest/installation.html but when I just use !pip install cltk I get this error and I'm not sure what to do since I doubt that the project is actually compromised:

ERROR: Error [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software while executing command python setup.py egg_info
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software

Thanks in advance for any help!